# Unable to click on Element getting exception like "Element is not currently visible and so may not be interacted with"

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver

I am unable to click on element

Below is the properties of element that I tried to click on that

```
<div class="btn-group bootstrap-select open" style="top: 246.983px; left: 537px; width: 220px; position: absolute;">
<div class="dropdown-menu open" style="overflow: hidden; min-height: 92px;">
<ul class="dropdown-menu inner" role="menu" style="overflow-y: auto; min-height: 80px;">
<li class="" data-original-index="0">
<li class="selected" data-original-index="1">
<a data-tokens="null" data-normalized-text="<span class="text">Editing Workflow</span>" tabindex="0">
```

The code i tried is

```
**driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[@class='dropdown-menu open']//span[contains(text(), 'Editing Workflow')]")).click();**
```

but it is giving exception as below
Corresponding StackTrace

```
:org.openqa.selenium.ElementNotVisibleException: Element is not currently visible and so may not be interacted with
```

Then I tried with below javascriptExecutor code

```
((JavascriptExecutor) Initialization.driver).executeScript("arguments[0].setAttribute('visibility', 'true');", this.wbElement);
```

but still it is giving below exception

```
**2016-04-28 14:07:37 PM DEBUG [main] (ElmKeywordLib.java : 171) - Corresponding StackTrace :org.openqa.selenium.ElementNotVisibleException: Element is not currently visible and so may not be interacted with
Command duration or timeout: 45.18 seconds
Build info: version: '2.39.0', revision: '14fa800511cc5d66d426e08b0b2ab926c7ed7398', time: '2013-12-16 13:18:38'
System info: host: 'BLRKEC254298D', ip: '144.114.236.243', os.name: 'Windows 7', os.arch: 'x86', os.version: '6.1', java.version: '1.7.0_07'
Session ID: ee1d1fdd-7e46-4bba-abf3-837dcd54e54a
Driver info: org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver
Capabilities [{platform=XP, databaseEnabled=true, cssSelectorsEnabled=true, javascriptEnabled=true, acceptSslCerts=true, handlesAlerts=true, browserName=firefox, webStorageEnabled=true, nativeEvents=false, rotatable=false, locationContextEnabled=true, applicationCacheEnabled=true, takesScreenshot=true, version=31.0}]**
```

Please help on this. Waiting for reply...

Source code:

```
  public void selectTDWorkflowType() {

            for (iflagCounter = 1;iflagCounter <= CommonFile.iStepsToExeCount && KeywordLibrary.isTestScenarioContinue;iflagCounter++){
                fnDisplayStepCount();

                if (CommonFile.strStepsToExecute.charAt(iflagCounter - 1)!='0'){
                    switch(CommonFile.iBpcExecutingCaseNum = iflagCounter){

                case 1:


this.objKeywordLibrary.klWebElementClick(ObjectMap.OR_TD_BTN_WORKFLOW_TYPE_CREATEWF, ObjectMap.S_TD_BTN_WORKFLOW_TYPE_CREATEWF);
                        this.objKeywordLibrary.klSetAttriToMakeEleVisible(ObjectMap.OR_TD_BTN_WORKFLOWTYPE_EDITINGL_CREATEWF, ObjectMap.S_TD_BTN_WORKFLOWTYPE_EDITINGL_CREATEWF);
                        this.objKeywordLibrary.klWebElementClick(ObjectMap.OR_TD_BTN_WORKFLOWTYPE_EDITINGL_CREATEWF, ObjectMap.S_TD_BTN_WORKFLOWTYPE_EDITINGL_CREATEWF);
    //                  this.objKeywordLibrary.klListSelectbyText(ObjectMap.S_TD_BTN_WORKFLOW_TYPE_CREATEWF, "WorkflowType", true);
                        break;

default:
    LOGGER.warn(StringConstants.STRSTEPEXEINFO);
    break;                                              
                    }
                }
                else
                    LOGGER.info(StringConstants.STRBPCEXEINFO);
            }    
        }


    public void klSetAttriToMakeEleVisible(String strFindProperty, String strName)
         {

            try {

                if(klIsElementPresentNoReport(strFindProperty)){

                    this.wbElement = Initialization.driver.findElement(By.xpath(strFindProperty));
                                    ((JavascriptExecutor) Initialization.driver).executeScript("arguments[0].setAttribute('visibility', 'true');", this.wbElement);
    //              this.wbElement.click();
                    ((JavascriptExecutor) Initialization.driver).executeScript("arguments[0].click;", this.wbElement);
                    this.wbElement.click();


    public void klSetAttriToMakeEleVisible(String strFindProperty, String strName)
         {

            try {

                if(klIsElementPresentNoReport(strFindProperty)){

                    this.wbElement = Initialization.driver.findElement(By.xpath(strFindProperty));

                    ((JavascriptExecutor) Initialization.driver).executeScript("arguments[0].setAttribute('visibility', 'true');", this.wbElement);
    //              this.wbElement.click();
                    ((JavascriptExecutor) Initialization.driver).executeScript("arguments[0].click;", this.wbElement);
                    this.wbElement.click();


    }catch (NoSuchElementException e) {
                LOGGER.debug(StringConstants.STRSTACKTRACE+ e);
                ReportingFunctionsXml.fnSetReportBPCStepStatus(false, strName, "",String.format(StringConstants.STRCLRELEEXPECTED,strName), StringConstants.STRNOSUCHELEEXCEP.concat(StringConstants.STRCHKLOG));
            }catch (UnreachableBrowserException e) {
                LOGGER.debug(StringConstants.STRSTACKTRACE+ e);
                ReportingFunctionsXml.fnSetReportBPCStepStatus(false, strName, "",String.format(StringConstants.STRCLRELEEXPECTED,strName), StringConstants.STRUNRECBROWEXCEP);
                RecoveryScn.recUnReachableTestScnExitTrue();
            }catch (WebDriverException e) {
                LOGGER.debug(StringConstants.STRSTACKTRACE+ e);
                ReportingFunctionsXml.fnSetReportBPCStepStatus(false, strName, "",String.format(StringConstants.STRCLRELEEXPECTED,strName), StringConstants.STRWEBDRVEXCEP);
            }
        }


    public boolean klWebElementClick(String strFindProperty, String strName)
        {
            boolean bReturnStatus = false;
            try {
    for(int i=0;i<=2;i++)

                {

                    //                try{
                    if (klIsElementPresentNoReport(strFindProperty)){
                        this.wbElement.isDisplayed();
                        System.out.println("Is element is displayed/visible: "+this.wbElement.isDisplayed());

                        this.wbElement.click();
                        klWait(1000);
                        ReportingFunctionsXml.fnSetReportBPCStepStatus(true, strName,
                                "", String.format(StringConstants.STRCLKELEEXPECTED,strName), String.format(StringConstants.STRCLKELESUCCS,strName));
                        this.wbElement=null;
                        bReturnStatus = true;
                    } else 
                        ReportingFunctionsXml.fnSetReportBPCStepStatus(false, strName,
                                "",  String.format(StringConstants.STRCLKELEEXPECTED,strName), String.format(StringConstants.STRCLKELEFAILURE,strName));


                    break;
    }

                }catch (NoSuchElementException e) {
                LOGGER.debug(StringConstants.STRSTACKTRACE+ e);
                LOGGER.error(StringConstants.STRNOSUCHELEEXCEP);
                ReportingFunctionsXml.fnSetReportBPCStepStatus(false, strName, "",
                        String.format(StringConstants.STRCLKELEEXPECTED,strName), StringConstants.STRNOSUCHELEEXCEP);
            }catch (UnreachableBrowserException e) {
                LOGGER.debug(StringConstants.STRSTACKTRACE+ e);
                LOGGER.error(StringConstants.STRUNRECBROWEXCEP);
                ReportingFunctionsXml.fnSetReportBPCStepStatus(false, strName, "",
                        String.format(StringConstants.STRCLKELEEXPECTED,strName), StringConstants.STRUNRECBROWEXCEP);
                RecoveryScn.recUnReachableTestScnExitTrue();
            }catch (WebDriverException e) {
                LOGGER.debug(StringConstants.STRSTACKTRACE+ e);
                LOGGER.error("\t"+StringConstants.STRWEBDRVEXCEP);
                ReportingFunctionsXml.fnSetReportBPCStepStatus(false, strName, "",
                        String.format(StringConstants.STRCLKELEEXPECTED,strName),  StringConstants.STRWEBDRVEXCEP);
            }return bReturnStatus;

    }

Objects (Xpath and Description):
**public static final String OR_TD_BTN_WORKFLOWTYPE_EDITINGL_CREATEWF= "//div[@class='dropdown-menu open']//span[contains(text(), 'Editing Workflow')]";
    public static final String S_TD_BTN_WORKFLOWTYPE_EDITINGL_CREATEWF= "TD_Editing Workflow option in Workflow Type drop-list of Create Workflow screen";**
```

Thanks
Shantaveer

Comment: please post the source code as well

Comment: before clicking on that element, do u use this function --wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(your locator));

Comment: No and that element is drop-list value

Comment: no i mean page source code not the selenium source code

Comment: <div class="dropdown-menu open" style="overflow: hidden; min-height: 92px;">
<ul class="dropdown-menu inner" role="menu" style="overflow-y: auto; min-height: 80px;">
<li class="" data-original-index="0">
<li class="selected" data-original-index="1">
<a data-tokens="null" data-normalized-text="<span class="text">Editing Workflow</span>" tabindex="0">
<span class="text">Editing Workflow</span>
<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-ok check-mark"/>

Comment: <a data-tokens="null" data-normalized-text="<span class="text">Editing Workflow</span>" tabindex="0">
<span class="text">Editing Workflow</span>
<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-ok check-mark"/>

Comment: first click on dropdown, than before clicking on any dropdown option, use the wait function

Comment: Ok will try and update u

Comment: @noor, I tried with wait but still it is not working

Comment: how many second u use?can u please share ur link if possible?

Comment: just give me the code u use only for -------- first click on dropdown, than before clicking on any dropdown option, use the wait function

Comment: Sorry we can open with office n/w only

Comment: actually ur error message means Element is not currently visible before click,so if wait is not worked , than check ur locator is correct, check by using cssselector instead of xpath. I have one more solution using javascript but u already tried it....if all these guess is not worked, than without navigating to ur url, it is tough for solution.